# Mostrar Diferencia de 2 instantes en formato SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") android

Tags: android, timestamp

Tengo 2 botones que obtienen el timestamp de Inicio, fin y duracion de un evento, pero se ven como java.text.SimpleDateFormat@f17b4ca5, pero no sé como calcular la diferencia entre ambos.

Me gustaria que se viera de esta forma: "2018-04-15-14:34:24.567"

varibles de MainActivity.java

```
SimpleDateFormat timestampFin = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
SimpleDateFormat timestampInicio = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

public void DefinirHoraInicio(View view)
{
    inicio = timestampInicio.toString();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inicio del evento: " + inicio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    viewInicio.setText(inicio);

}

public void DefinirHoraFin(View view)
{
    String Duracion = "";
    fin = timestampFin.toString();
    //Duracion = (timestampFin - timestampInicio).toString();
    Duracion = fin;

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fin del evento: " + fin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    viewFin.setText(fin);
    viewDuracion.setText(Duracion);
}
```

Comment: y esos botones como obtienen el timestamp? o como obtienes el timestamp?

Comment: con Calendar.getInstance(), con lo que está de código que proporcionó @Elenasys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` se usa para obtener o definir el formato que deseas, en este caso

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

pero estas obteniendo valores como   `java.text.SimpleDateFormat@f17b4ca5`, ya que solo estas imprimiendo la representación a String del formato.

```
inicio = timestampInicio.toString();
 fin = timestampFin.toString();
```

Para obtener la diferencia entre 2 fechas es necesario definas la inicial y la final, como ejemplo:

```
        String strInicio = "2018-04-18 10:10:09.000";
        String strFin = "2018-04-18 11:10:09.000";
```

Si deseas obtener estas fechas en formato String, puedes usar este método:

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

el cual puedes llamar de esta forma, definiendo el formato que deseas utilizar:

```
  String strInicio = getDate(System.currentTimeMillis(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

A partir de estas fechas se usa el formato adecuado y se obtiene la diferencia que deseas:

```
   try {
        Date dInicio = timestampInicio.parse(strInicio);
        Date dFin = timestampFin.parse(strFin);


        long diferencia = (dFin.getTime() - dInicio.getTime()) / 1000;
        Log.i(TAG,"Diferencia : "  + diferencia );

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

En este caso la diferencia es de 3600 segundos, que convertido a minutos son 60.

Comment: Veo que necesita estar el proyecto a partir de la API 27 de android para utilizar Calendar, no habrá problemas si lo llego a usar en un proyecto como plataforma mínima la API 24?

Comment: Holaa @Kuroi , no necesita estar a partir de API 27 Calendar existe desde API 1 : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Probé el código y me pide importar jav.util.calendar en andorid studio 3 y me dice alguno de sus métodos son de la api 27

Comment: @Kuroi como cual método?, en tu build.gradle puedes definir una API mínima mediante, como ejemplo API 15 :  minSdkVersion 15 .Por cierto yo uso targetSdkVersion 25 y no tengo problemas.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero no compila el proyecto por no ser de la api minima indicada por android studio